# Creating a generic server-side validation function in Coldfusion

Tags: forms, coldfusion, validation

So, I've been trying to clean up my code and learn things that I should always do...well of course server-side validation is one of those things that I should always do. However, what happens when I have this huge form? I really would like to have a generic function that allows me to pass the data type and field name. Is there a secure way to do this in Coldfusion?

I've been looking into doing this for a while, but I've come to dead ends and can't find any info on doing something like this on the web. It seems like Coldfusion does not offer this ability.

However, I think it would be cool if there was a way to specify an attribute in your input tags that had the data type of the field. Then, it would be uber nice if Coldfusion stuck it into a struct for you with your field names.

Is there anyway to accomplish this or can someone elaborate on the most efficient way to do server-side validation?

Comment: Look into ValidateThis - very cool, very powerful, very easy to use validation library.  http://www.validatethis.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be great if CF had something like that!  Good news, it does, for years now!  :)

What you're looking for is `cfinput` (and `cfform`) tag.  This tag includes the validation specifics right in the tag like you're wanting (great minds think alike, right?).  You can specify the validation, the error message, if it should validate client or server side - all kinds of neat tricks.

Check here for implementation - it's quite easy to use:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_07.html

Be warned that a lot of code diva's hate cfform / cfinput.  In reality, there is nothing wrong with them when implemented correctly.  It can be abused and it won't fit for every solution, but that is true of everything in the toolbox.  By and large, for most form input and validation situations it works great.

If you hate that idea, another is to use the built in type attribute of `cfparam` and catch your errors.

For example, at the top of your form processing page, you can :

```
<cfparam name="form.cardNumber" type="creditcard">
```

When this is reached, if the value in that variable is not of that type, it will throw an exception that you can catch.  This keeps you from having to write the if() and pattern matching.  Additionally, if there isn't a type built in, you can specify a regular expression for pattern matching.

Here's some more information and the types supported: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_01.html

Let me know what you think!

Comment: I'm aware of cfform and cfinput, however I've read that it is good to have both client and server-side validation. cfinput is client-side and if you disable javascript...well you got no validation. I actually already have those tags. I'm just looking to secure my forms with server side too! :) However, I didn't know cfparam had a type. That is interesting and exactly what I was looking for! (I didn't want to type out the if pattern matching.)

Comment: Remember that you can make cfinput server side validation rather than client side too!  :)   validateAt="onServer"  - done!

Comment: ColdFusion has some very good inbuilt validation that has already been stated by Nate. I personally like validate this @ http://www.validatethis.org/. It works very well with ORM in CF9 has some cool client side and server side validation. The best thing is your configuration is from one location. easy to use too :)

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to look at possibly using a ColdFusion framework like CFWheels (or ColdBox) which has a lot of this type of functionality already built in to make development a TON easier. Using CFWheels has been one of the best decisions I've made as a developer and my development skills have grown significantly over the past year. There's some great screencasts online to get started. http://cfwheels.org/screencasts